# Is it considered acceptable to write "he went through the door"?

Tags: prepositions

> He panicked and went through the nearest door.

Is it considered acceptable to write "went **through** the nearest door" to avoid taking the tension and flow out of the story by describing that he opens the door and then enters?

Comment: Yes that works.

Comment: Yes, in the same way that you say "drink from the cup" and not the belaboured "pick up the cup and drink from it", and also "put the kettle on" and not "filled the kettle with water and switched on the electricity".

Comment: It is acceptable but not particularly descriptive prose. Other verbs are more impactful, such as **ran**, **sped**, **fled**, and so on. Depending on your context, you might receive negative feedback for that reason.

Comment: @FeliniusRex yeah a more specific verb might be better. I'd also say that (for British English at least)  *went through* can imply colliding with something and passing through it. If you're talking about *where* someone went, the route they took, then *she went through that door* sounds normal. If you're just talking about someone passing through a door, and the verb you use to describe that action is *went*, it can sound like crashing through. *He went through a glass door* sounds like a terrible accident!

Answer (score 1):

**Being a native American I'd say:**
If you say "He can walk through doors" it sounds like you mean he walks through the door (through the wood), and that perhaps he is a ghost.
But if you say "He goes through the door" it sounds like you mean the doorway.

However I can't find any valid or grammatical reason for it to be like that.

Have a look at [this link](https://www.gymglish.com/en/gymglish/english-translation/through-the-door) for a bit more understanding.

Answer (score 1):

I would agree that

> He panicked and went through the nearest door.

is perfectly acceptable and idiomatic. However, as some of the comments suggest, particularly in view of the use of the verb "panicked", this might be misread as meaning:

> He panicked and went through the nearest door without bothering to open it first.

Assuming that isn't what you mean and you want this sentence to be simple and brief to get on with the action, you could write:

> He panicked and went out the nearest door.

If you want it still simple you could write something like

> He panicked and ran out the nearest door.

other verbs such as "leaped" or "dashed" could be used in a similar way.

Or one could develop the situation more, such as

> He panicked when he saw John, and ran out the nearest door, thinking: "I'll never be able to come back here again. Not in a million years!"

This is all a matter of style, and of the intended effect of the sentence in the work of which it is a part.